# Replacing SQL field content from pattern till the end of line

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am struggling with a problem in my database. Basically, I have lots of data with various content but luckily I have always added "Kind Regards" keywords in posts and after that I have added various social media links. The links are sometimes the same and sometimes different. But the keyword "Kind Regards" is always there.
The structure is like this

```
Kind Regards 
Linkedin Facebook Google Image link 
Some Random Text
```

I want to replace **everything after Kind Regards including Kind Regards** with just **Kind Regards R**

i.e. I want to replace "Kind Regards blah_links blah_link blah_links" with just "Kind Regards R"

I tried following query in SQL tab of phpmyadmin but it didin't affect anything

```
    UPDATE wl_content SET message = REPLACE(message,'Kind Regards%','Kind Regards R')
```

I hope anyone can guide me on how to do this replace.

Comment: Remove percent char. `REPLACE(message,'Kind Regards','Kind Regards R')`. This is literal, not pattern.

Comment: If I replace the %, then it will just replace "Kind Regards". Not all the content after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE wl_content 
SET message = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(message,
                                     'Kind Regards', 
                                     1), 
                     'Kind Regards R')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9983c42e2e1daa412c9022612258ab59)

Comment: Hi Akina,
The structure is like this

```
Kind Regards
Linkedin Facebook Google 
Image link
Some Random Text
```


I want to replace all **everything after Kind Regards including Kind Regards** with just **Kind Regards R**

Comment: @RajeshNeesh Fiddle added. If you find some incorrectness - edit source data and post new link and desired output for it.

Comment: You are awesome Akina :)